# MultiStep Form - Cannot update during an existing state transition error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a multi-stage form in React. I build a simple demo to try out the functionality of going through the form. As a template, I used [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-multistep-forms-with-react-and-semantic-ui) tutorial I found on the web.
The error message I am getting is 
`Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within "render"). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`
after I click on the continue button.

I looked through multiple StackOverflow questions, which had the same error message, but none helped me to resolve my issue.

**MainForm**

```
export class MainForm extends Component {
    state = {
        step: 1
    };

    nextStep = () => {
        const {step} = this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step + 1
        });
    };

    prevStep = () => {
        const {step} = this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step - 1
        });
    };

    render() {
        const {step} = this.state;

        switch (step) {
            case 1:
                return (
                    <PatientDetails
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                    />
                );
            case 2:
                return(
                    <Summary
                        prevStep={this.prevStep()}
                    />
                );
            default:
                return(
                    <h1>Something went wrong, kiddo</h1>
                );

        }
    }
}

export default MainForm
```

**PatientDetails**

```
export class PatientDetails extends Component {

    continue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Form horizontal>
                <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.continue}>Continue</Button>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

export default PatientDetails;
```

**Summary**

```
export class Summary extends Component {

    back = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Form horizontal>
                <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.back}>Continue</Button>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

export default Summary;
```

Comment: In your code your handler is wrong at `prevStep={this.prevStep()}` you have wrong parentheses there and it should most likely be just `prevStep={this.prevStep}`. So during `render` it attempts to call the method right away which calls `setState` and triggers the warning.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic - yes, that was it, thanks a lot. Is it possible to mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: I just created an answer instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the comments, the warning indicates that `setState` is (unintentionally) being called in the middle of the `render` call.

Looking at your code the culprit is to be found for when you attempt to render the `Summary` component as the handler you pass to it, is accidentally being called since you wrote `prevStep={this.prevStep()}`. By removing the parentheses and writing `prevStep={this.prevStep}` your issue should be fixed.